# Big responsive background image - which resolution?

Tags: css, image, background, resolution

I'm developing a website for a photographer. The landing page is made of a big responsive background image and a menu. I know how to make a responsive background image, but the question I have is : Which resolution should the image be? Should I get 2-3 different sizes and apply them depending on the device width or one which I would reduce? Which should be the biggest size for the biggest screens? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Focus more on compression and format than resolution. If you use caching and compression on the server you won't need to decrease the resolution of the image. As for this question:

> Should I get 2-3 different sizes and apply them depending on the device width or one which I would reduce?

Use the same image for all screens. Also note that changing the image size attribute doesn't decrease load times, it just resizes the image after downloading it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I agree with Random User 100%. I would, if possible, use differently sized images for different media sizes. Since theres a huge range of screen sizes, and also a huge range of bandwidth limitations, If you can serve the smallest possible image size for the screen, it will have a large effect on load times. While Random User may be correct about compression and the size attribute, BUT caching won't help if users are loading your page for the first time. A high-res image loading on a 3G connection is gonna hang up your page load, one way or another.

Currently there isn't wide support natively in browsers for responsive images (yet), such as the [srcset attibute or the picture element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html), but there are Javascript alternatives. The one I use is [Interchange](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html), part of the [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) framework.

You do want to be careful that you are not trading image loading savings for Javascript loading losses. However, in general, javascript libraries are fairly small, and the additional HTTP request for a JS file will usually be outweighed by the savings gained by not loading a massive image on a mobile device. I would recommend combining and compressing your Javascript into a single file, but thats another thing altogether.

Comment: I would also add that specifying separate images for screen sizes has the added benefit of being able to use different images altogether. For example, you may want a different crop or narrow aspect ratio for a small screen layout, but a wide crop and aspect ratio for widescreen layout. Just something else to keep in mind.

Comment: If I want an image to work correctly in full-screen on, let's say, computer screens, which size should the image be? 1800 width? 1500?  This is what I want to know because I wouldn't want a big screen user to come around my website and lose the navigating motion I tried to create by viewing a background color on the sides.

Comment: I have a carousel on my Mobile App and each image is 3mb so it makes sense, even if you are doing caching the first time the page load is really slow